# How to prove $f(x)=\max({\int_{0}^{x}(t-t^2)\sin^{2n}{t}dt})\le\frac{1}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}$ $(x\ge0$, $n\in{N})$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Since $f'(x)=0$ when $x=1$ and $>0$ on the left $<0$ on the right, $f(x)\le{f(1)}$. But I don't know what to do next. Would you tell me how to slove it? Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ the function
$$ g_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x}(t-t^2)\sin^{2n}(t)\,dt $$
clearly is differentiable. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus the stationary points of $g_n$ occur at the zeroes of $(t-t^2)\sin(t)$, i.e. at $\{-1,1\}\cup\pi\mathbb{Z}$. It is not difficult to check that $g_n(x)$ is negative on $[\pi,+\infty)$ (since $g_n(\pi)<0$ and $g_n'(x)\leq 0$ on $[\pi,+\infty)$), hence
$$ \max_{x\geq 0}g_n(x) = g_n(1) = \int_{0}^{1}(t-t^2)\sin^{2n}(t)\,dt\leq\int_{0}^{1}(t-t^2)t^{2n}\,dt=\frac{1}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}. $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** for $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $\sin^2(t)\le t^2$.